# Calculating a ratio from two columns of data by parameters set in another column

Tags: r

I have date values in wide from and I'm trying to calculate the ratio of the date value with the baseline only within the Start Date and End Dates.

For example:

```
ID   Start Date  End Date  Baseline 1/18 2/18 3/18 4/18 5/18 6/18 7/18 8/18     
A    1/1/2018    5/1/2018     5      2    4     1    3    5    2    4    5
B    6/1/2018    8/1/2018     2      4    2     4    3    6    6    2    1  
C    2/1/2018    3/1/2018     8      3    5     5    3    2    7    8    2
D    5/1/2015    7/1/2018     9      1    3     5    7    4    8    9    1
```

I would like to output to be:

```
ID   Start Date  End Date  Baseline 1/18 2/18 3/18 4/18 5/18 6/18 7/18 8/18     
A    1/1/2018    5/1/2018     5     0.4  0.8   0.2  0.6   1            
B    6/1/2018    8/1/2018     2                                3    1  0.5
C    2/1/2018    3/1/2018     8         0.625 0.625    
D    5/1/2015    7/1/2018     9                         0.44  0.88  1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A very inelegant solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, which someone can probably build on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample <- sample %>% mutate_at(vars(5:12), funs(round(./Baseline, digits = 3))) ## perform the initial simple proportion calculation

sample <- sample %>% gather(5:12, key = "day", value = "value") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% ## allow for rowwise operations
  mutate(value_temp = case_when(any(grepl(as.numeric(str_extract(day, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")), 
                                                        as.numeric(str_extract(StartDate, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")):as.numeric(str_extract(EndDate, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")))) == T ~ T, 
                                TRUE ~ NA)) ## create a logical vector which indicates TRUE if the "day" is included in the range of days of StartDate and EndDate

sample$value[is.na(sample$value_temp)] <- NA ## sets values which aren't included in the vector of days to NA
sample$value_temp <- NULL ## remove the temp variable
sample <- sample %>%  spread(day, value) ## spread to original df


> sample
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  ID    StartDate EndDate  Baseline `1/18` `2/18` `3/18` `4/18` `5/18` `6/18` `7/18` `8/18`
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     1/1/2018  5/1/2018        5    0.4  0.8    0.2      0.6  1     NA         NA   NA  
2 B     6/1/2018  8/1/2018        2   NA   NA     NA       NA   NA      3          1    0.5
3 C     2/1/2018  3/1/2018        8   NA    0.625  0.625   NA   NA     NA         NA   NA  
4 D     5/1/2015  7/1/2018        9   NA   NA     NA       NA    0.444  0.889      1   NA
```

**Update:**

```
sample <- sample %>% mutate_at(vars(5:12), funs(round(./Baseline, digits = 3)))

sample <- sample %>% gather(5:12, key = "day", value = "value") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(value_temp = case_when(any(grepl(as.numeric(str_extract(day, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")), 
                                          as.numeric(str_extract(Start_Date, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")):as.numeric(str_extract(End_Date, "^[:digit:]{1,2}(?=/)")))) == T & 
                                  any(grepl(as.numeric(str_extract(day, "[:digit:]{2}$")), 
                                        as.numeric(str_extract(Start_Date, "[:digit:]{2}$")):as.numeric(str_extract(End_Date, "[:digit:]{2}$")))) ~ T, 
                                TRUE ~ NA))

sample$value[is.na(sample$value_temp)] <- NA
sample$value_temp <- NULL
sample$day <- sample$day %>% as_factor()
sample <- sample %>% spread(day, value)
```

Comment: Hi VY, thank you for the help. I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I believe the section of code where a logical vector is crated that indicates TRUE if the "day" is included in the range of days of StartDate and EndDate only works for the example. In my actual data set, a day of 07/12 would fall in between a start date of 04/18 and 09/18, which is false.

Comment: I updated the code, try that. It accounts for the year (assuming two digit format) and preserves order of the original time variables.